# Faster way to compute `nchoosek` in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to find a faster code than using `P = nchoosek(1:100,i)`, which is located in a loop, and repeated `i` times in my code.

Comment: What are the typical values of `i` you are using?

Comment: @Divakar: It is up to 10

Comment: The matrix you are trying to compute is something like 1 petabyte if I'm correct. Even if I'm out by several orders of magnitude, it's way way too big to even think about. I think you need to come up with a different method.

Comment: Please provide the code where this is being used and an explanation of what you want to do with it.  We cannot help you find an alternative unless we know what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [`VChoosek(v,k)`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQjBAwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fmatlabcentral%2Ffileexchange%2F26190-vchoosek%2Fcontent%2FVChooseK.m&ei=-9M0VbD1HoGXsAHN34DgBQ&usg=AFQjCNG4TtDkPqa6ox1L2lnEv9zFAa8yOQ&sig2=KB0WqvPOSsCpXk49McaHhg) is much faster than `nchoosek`.

Answer (score 5):

`nchoosek(1:100,10)` is absolutely vast, far bigger than any typical machine could hold in memory.

The MATLAB documentation for `nchoosek` says

> `C = nchoosek(v,k)` is only practical for situations where `length(v)` is less than about `15`.

You're not really going to be able to do this.